# css: all td only if table has th

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

There is a valid css rule (jquery only as last chance) that permit to define style of all td's of a table only if there are a th row.

To be more specific

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      STYLE 1 HERE, my background color is white
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>
      some text
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      STYLE 2 HERE, my table has TH, my background color is red
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
th, td {
    background-color:#ffffff
       }

?????? {
         background-color:#ff0000
       }
```

there is a way?

thanks in advance,
cicciopas

Answer (score 3):

In css, you can't really do this. There's the `+` "adjacent" select, but that requires that the nodes share an immediate common parent. If you had a row of mixed `<td></td><th></th>`, then they'd qualify for this. But your th and td cells are in different rows, so they don't share a common `<tr>` parent.

So:

```
th + td {
   color: red
}
```

would work for

```
<tr>
   <th>Look ma, I'm red!</th>
   <td>ooer, a header</td>
</tr>
```

because they share the same parent `<tr>`, but

```
<tr>
   <th>Header</th>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>Dang, not red</td>
</tr>
```

won't, because there's two different parents for the th/td nodes.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is slightly wrong in that your css for the first instance of background white should be

```
tr,td {
     background-color:'ffffff;
}
```

And if what i garner your trying to do is set the background of `<td>` tags in a table which has a `<th>` in it then through pure css you can't do this the way you have envisaged.

However a better way would be to append a class onto the `td` tags you want to style as demonstrated by this js fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/zYQ9h/

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you can't, as we would need the "Parent" selector, something like:

```
tr < th ~ tr td { background-color: red; }
```

This could be read as *"find any tr that contains a th, and apply a red background to it`s tr td siblings"*.

Unfortunately, there's no such thing as the `<` selector, so i'm afraid you'll have to throw some jQuery:

```
$("table:has(tr th)").find("tr td").css("background-color","red");
```

The `has()` in the jQuery selector does exactly what our wished `>` css selector would.